# VSTO Code-Behind Excel Document

Tags: excel, winforms, c#-4.0, vsto

I would like to create VSTO code-behind Excel document using Visual Studio 2015. User can only see presentation of data on Excel sheets but not editable. A window form will be attached to that particular Excel workbook and only user can input data on Winform and digest and reflect data on Excel sheets. Any piece of code fragment can achieve this?

Attached Excel in Form_Load function

```
excelApp=(Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

In Button Click

```
Excel.Worksheet wb=excelApp.Workbooks.get_Item(workbookName);
Excel.Worksheet sht=wb.Sheets.get_Item(sheetName);
Excel.Range startCell=sht.Range["A1"];
startCell.FormulaR1C1=textbox1.Text;
startCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1=textbox2.Text;
...
```

Is there any restriction can apply by code behind so that only input from Form1 go to sheet cell data?

Comment: Please let us know what you did and what questions you have. Your question is too generic

Comment: Excel worksheets/workbooks can be protected(with different protection options). If you go to the REVIEW tab on an Excel sheet, and play around with the options there. If that's the effect that you require, then it can be configured by C#.

Answer (score 1):

Attached Excel in Form_Load function

```
excelApp=(Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

In Button Click

```
Excel.Workbook wb=excelApp.Workbooks.get_Item(workbookName);

Excel.Worksheet sht=wb.Sheets.get_Item(sheetName);
sht.Unprotect(passwordToProtect);
Excel.Range startCell=sht.Range["A1"];
startCell.FormulaR1C1=textbox1.Text;
startCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1=textbox2.Text;
...// Do editing cell content here 
sht.Protect(userInterfaceOnly:true, password:passwordToProtect);
...
```